Pytorch dataloader running for over 20 minutes in a test case
I havent used Pytorch in a while and was trying to work on an completed Kaggle CV competition (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/isic-2024-challenge)
The training data contains a folder of images along with a csv file that contains additional metadata for each image and its target label. My initial attempt is to basically create a dataset that loads the image paths and the image labels from the csv file. Here is my code:

import os
import torch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, utils
from PIL import Image
# Ignore warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

class ILSCDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Dataset for ILSC competition. It contains the csv file with metadata and the images
    """
    def __init__(self, csv_file, img_path, transform=None):
        self.metadata = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.metadata.set_index('isic_id', inplace=True)
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.imgfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(img_path) if f.endswith('.jpg') and
                         os.path.splitext(f)[0] in self.metadata.index]
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgfiles)  # Changed from len(self.metadata) to len(self.imgfiles)
   
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.img_path, self.imgfiles[idx])
        image = Image.open(img_name)
        
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        image_id = os.path.splitext(self.imgfiles[idx])[0]
        metadata = self.metadata.loc[image_id]
        target = metadata['target']
        
        return image, target

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),  # Resize images to 224x224
    transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert images to PyTorch tensors
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])  # Normalize with ImageNet stats
])

ilsc_ds = ILSCDataset(csv_file='train-metadata.csv',
                      img_path='train-image/image',
                      transform=transform)

batch_size = 1
dataloader = DataLoader(ilsc_ds, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=6, pin_memory=True)

I just want to check if everthing is working fine before doing the CNN architecture, so I tried to test with this simple step
for images, targets in dataloader:
    print(f"Batch shape: {images.shape}")
    print(f"Targets shape: {targets.shape}")
    break  # Just print the first batch and break

But this is has been running for like 10 minutes. I thought it would just load one image file as the batchsize is 1 and then break out. Is there any issue in my code?
I ran each step of the dataset getitem manually and it seems to work

At first glance it looks fine, you can try again with num_workers=0 to stay in one process. Maybe something on your system hinders parallelization? If 0 workers are also stuck try again with the debugger where the process gets stuck; during loading of an image, transformation, or even earlier.

Hello, I set the num_workers to 0 and it works pretty fast. But the moment I increase it to two it just gets stuck. Any pointers on how to even begin debugging this?

I think this is then hardware limited. In general you can do about num_workers=<cpus on your system>. If you have only a single core you should likely stay with 0, I doubt 1 would bring you benefit. If you know you have multiple cores try to research in that direction and possibly ask a more general question how you can test and debug paralelism.
